# node.js twitter retrieve async to sync

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, twitter, synchronization

I use the twitter package to retrieve tweets and I want to call the retrieveTweets function some times and set the min id_str as max_id in the next function call.How I can implement sync call function some times.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var oAuthConnection = new Titter({
    consumer_key: '',
    consumer_secret: '',
    access_token_key: '',
    access_token_secret: ''
});
var params = {
    screen_name: '@cnn',
    count:200,
    max_id:'....'
};
function retrieveTweets(){
 oAuthConnection.get('statuses/user_timeline',params,function(err,tweets,res){
   var max_id = tweets[tweets.length-1].id_str;
   params.max_id = max_id
 });
}
```